# Implementing Single Sign On(SSO) Using SAML 2.0 in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, openid, saml-2.0

I have a requirement like there are three different applications(Application 1, Application 2, Application 3) each have different logins and hosted in different domains.Client want to implement SSO with these three applications using SAML.

I have an approach that there is a separate centralized DB for authenticating users for the three applications. If that is so whats the need of SAML with these. When should i use SAML to implement SSO?

Also if user logged in Application 1,he/she can able to login to Application 2 and Application 3 and vice-versa because there is links available within that application and we are able to identify the user using their generated token and redirect them to other application. But if user logged in Application 1 and he/she tries to login Application 2 or 3 in separate tab using direct url how should i identify the user and redirect to the destination application?

Thank you in Advance...